# Ubuntu-drivers-common don't recognize nvidia-driver-450

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

- Ubuntu18.04
- CUDA 10.0
- Kernel 5.3.0-53-generic

I updated the CUDA library from ver 10.2 to 11.0 following the NVIDIA's instruction [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=debnetwork).

GPU is correctly recognized as:

```
$ lspci  | grep -i "nvidia"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1ed0 (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f8 (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1ad8 (rev a1)
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1ad9 (rev a1)

$ nvidia-smi
Mon Jun  8 18:14:57 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.36.06    Driver Version: 450.36.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2080    On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   44C    P8     4W /  N/A |    118MiB /  7979MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2532      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 39MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2934      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               76MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, ubuntu-drivers-common don't recognize new nvidia-driver-450:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001ED0sv00001028sd000008C4bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
manual_install: True
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-418 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

I wonder why is it like? Do you have any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: How did you install the 450 driver? If you installed it from a run file, then it is normal.

Comment: I installed by deb installer as [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=debnetwork)

Comment: Anyway this applet is not supposed to track all 3rd party repos.

Answer (score 0):

The `ubuntu-drivers` utility is supposed to show drivers provided by Ubuntu.

It shows `manual_install: True`. This means that you have a manually installed driver. That seems really to be true ;-)

I see no problems anywhere.